# sum amounts with start and enddate by id

Tags: date, sas, intervals, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset for repayment loan amounts it consists of the following, perm_id( firm id), startyear endyear and date as well as repayment for each month.

I am trying to accumulate all repayment amounts per id per month and roll them off as the loans expire I have tried the following code;

```
    proc sql ;
create table want1 as
select a.perm_id,
       a.date,
       sum(b.repayment) as srepayment
    from work.want as a,
         work.want as b
    where a.perm_id = b.perm_id
      and b.date >= a.date
      
    group by a.perm_id, 
             a.date
;
```

However with the multiple overlapping loans it is giving very strange results

Any ideas?

I attempted to sum the amounts by date intervals however its picking up amounts that start later on and adds then to the very beginning.

Comment: Please provide sample data for us to work with. Makes it easier to provide a usable code answer.

Comment: Echoing Peter, reprex please.